# Force browser to render webpage's Print stylesheet

Tags: html, css, browser

A lot of web pages use a Print stylesheet to format things better for printing. My question is, is it possible to force the browser to render a page using the print stylesheet without actually printing it?

Comment: did this work for you? if so please make my answer

Comment: Google Chrome. Developer console. Override media:print

Answer (score 3, accepted):

usually the print css has a media type of print. simply remove the media definition and use it in replace of the main style sheet

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
```

change to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="print.css" />
```

Comment: Question was how to view any page with print css automatically, if it's present on the page.

Comment: which is what this would do. using a `print.css` as the main style sheet would cause the page to appear (as close as it could be) to what it will look like when printed

Comment: So I should on each page I visit during the day open my browser console, search for media="print" and edit it? :-)

Comment: ummm the OP was asking if where was a way to `force the browser to render a page using the print stylesheet without actually printing it`. So to my answer, instead of using the main style sheet make sure that the `print` style sheet does not have `media="print"`

Comment: Well, ok, I was too categorical. I googled yesterday for a way to force all pages to print mode and read this question with that in mind. Sorry I guess :-)

Comment: what if the printing statements are contained in the `@media print { }` block of the only stylesheet?

Comment: @Eonasdan don't be mad, but this answer doesn't solve what @interDist has said. The majority of the new pages use `@media print {}` nowadays.

Comment: @fiatjaf don't get mad? What I am 4? lol I wrote this 6 years ago

Comment: @Eonasdan, thank you for this post. It turned a 4 hour problem into a 10 second answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 15):

In Chrome (version 78), you can force the browser to render the webpage's print stylesheet using Chrome DevTools by going to **More Tools** > **Rendering**

[image: Open Chrome DevTools Rendering Settings]

then selecting the **Print** option in the *Emulate CSS Media* dropdown

[image: Emulate print media checkbox in Chrome DevTools]

Comment: Note this option is still available, but the UX has changed. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540990/using-chromes-element-inspector-in-print-preview-mode/21156904#21156904

Comment: Thanks @patricktokeeffe, I've updated this answer to match the updated UX as of Chrome 78. Thanks.