# Debug/inspect the print version of a web page

Tags: html, css, printing

I'm working on a small part of a large web site. I'm having some problems with the print version of a page, which uses `<css media="print">`. I wonder if there is a way of displaying the print version of the page in the browser, so that I can inspect it and find the errors.

Comment: Chromes developer tool has a built in print CSS emulator.  See these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540990/using-chromes-element-inspector-in-print-preview-mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extension Web developer (http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) has a display print style function that may help you.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a style sheet set to "screen" and another one set to "print" you could temporarily change the "print" one to also be "screen".

Comment: I thought about that, that is a good idea, but the site is so big, and I dont' have access to everything, so I'm not even sure what stuff is involved with the printing version. That's why I need to inspect the result with the developer tools.

Comment: The print stylesheet will probably either be a seperate stylesheet or it will be rules added to the main stylesheet - both methods will use media=print in some form. Just find that and pull it up in your editor. Then ht print preview in your browser and you'll see the printed version. Do a bit of compare and contrast. Not a great methiod admittedly but it should let you do the job. I'll try and think of something else that woul;d let you view the actual print version in the browser abut other than my original suggestion I'm not sure how you'll do that tbh.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to create another page which is optimized for printer (printer friendly page), and Just add `$(document).ready(function() {
window.print();
});` 
Then change the link to the 'print' button to this new file.