# Leaflet cluster group background color does not appear in map print export

Tags: css, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I have a Leaflet map with a L.markerClusterGroup. It looks like this:

[image]

But when printing (to PDF), it looks like this:

[image]

Notice the absence of background colour.

The points are created as follow:

```
L.DivIcon({ html: '<div><span>' + (childCount + tally) + '</span></div>', className: 'marker-cluster' + <my own css>, iconSize: new L.Point(40, 40) });
```

Where "my own css" are css classes that may be either of following:

```
background: rgba(255, 0, 192, 0.3); !important;
border: 1px solid #666;
```

Or

```
background: rgba(9, 243, 33, 0.6);!important;
border: 1px solid #666;
```

Anyone else ever had the same issue?

Comment: You have checked that your web browser gives you an option to keep backgrounds when printing, and that option is set to the right value, right?

Comment: IvanSanchez: yes I have and also followed the answer in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392366/print-background-colours-in-chrome

Comment: Try [emulating CSS media](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21247583/not-able-to-find-emulate-css-media-in-google-chrome) and see if there any print-specific changes in your CSS, maybe that'll give you more info.

Comment: Which browser do you use? I see that all your other backgrounds are not rendered (look at the zoom and layers controls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was bad CSS. `background: rgba(255, 0, 192, 0.3); !important;` instead of `background: rgba(255, 0, 192, 0.3) !important;`.

Here's the working CSS:

```
@media print {

  .my-own-css1, .my-own-css2, {
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;         
         background: rgba(255, 0, 192, 0.3) !important;
    }
}
```