# Using Bootstrap, CSS Print Media Rules work on Chrome, but not Firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, printing, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have added some `@media print` queries to a stylesheet to try to make the content more attractive and useful if printed out (typical stuff: remove navbar, interactive features, print links). It is working how I want on Chrome, but not on Firefox and Safari. (I'm taking about pages like [this](http://harlemshadows.org/the-easter-flower.html)).

The rules I've written to not display certain material, but the grid layout  behaves differently:

### Firefox

[image: Print CSS from Firefox]

### Chrome

[image: Print CSS from Chrome]

The additional `@print` styles are being applied to both, but Chrome reproduces the layout without any of the other media rules being applied (so it appears in one column---which is what I would like); Firefox does not.

I suspect my question is as much about Bootstrap as it is about `@print` queries *per se*. But before I start writing `@print` rules to try to reset Bootstrap's layout, is there something else I should understand about how browsers construct a page for print? Is there a simple solution to ensure other browsers produce something that looks like Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some additional poking around, and finding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21261752/printing-changes-bootstrap-based-layout-to-single-column-mode?rq=1) it seems as though Chrome sets the page width for printing to smaller than 768 pixels, so that Bootstrap uses the xs styles. [This issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12078) discusses it at length.

I liked the (perhaps odd) behavior of Chrome; to secure it on Firefox requires rewriting the bootstrap rules. What I came up with is something like this:

```
@media print {
 .col-sm-1,
 .col-sm-2,
 .col-sm-3,
 .col-sm-4,
 .col-sm-5,
 .col-sm-6,
 .col-sm-7,
 .col-sm-8,
 .col-sm-9,
 .col-sm-10,
 .col-sm-11,
 .col-sm-12 {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
 }
}
```

I'm not sure how *wise* a solution this, but it seems to be working.