# Switch HTML page to media print mode

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, media-queries

Is there a way to switch an HTML page to "print" mode?

When I print, a `@media print` style-sheet gets applied to the page.

I want to use the page with that print style applied to export to PDF as well. Ideally, if I could get the HTML that gets sent to the printer when I use `window.print()` I could export it to PDF. I use a server side library and C# to export to PDF.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Thank you!

Comment: How are you exporting to PDF? Can you just add the print stylesheet?

Comment: We have a server side library that exports HTML to PDF. I'm hoping to avoid having to manipulate the HTML with JQuery to add/remove styles...

Comment: Which server side language?

Comment: I'm using C# as server side language.

Comment: Add that to question and update the tags as well..

Comment: refer this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540990/using-chromes-element-inspector-in-print-preview-mode/

Answer (score 0):

As per W3C standars there is no distinctive print mode for web pages except that you can define different CSS rules for `@screen` and `@print` media.

If you want to render a page as it is shown in print view somewhere it is show in screen view; use `@print` CSS for `@screen` also.