# css print media query prints only first page

Tags: html, css, printing

I use Print Media Query to print a scrollable DIV on my webpage (Main DIV contains a sub DIV and table with several rows and custom styles from kendo grid). The window.Print() only prints one page in both IE 9 and Chrome chopping rest of the DIV contents. How would I make sure it prints all contents in multiple pages. I read similar posts for issue with Firefox but the solution of using overflow: visible !important did not work for me. Below is my style

Note: I've tried with position: absolute, height/width: 100% and setting same settings as below for Table, TBody, TR and TD, but no use.

```
@media print {

body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }

#divname, #divname* {
    visibility: visible;
  }

#divname
    {
        overflow: visible !important; 
        float:none !important;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        display:block !important;
        /*height:auto !important;*/
    }
}
```

EDIT: I finally managed to print by reading from DOM like below. In case, if it helps someone

```
    `//get DIV content as clone
    var divContents = $("#DIVNAME").clone();
    //detatch DOM body
    var body = $("body").detach();
    //create new body to hold just the DIV contents
    document.body = document.createElement("body");
    //add DIV content to body
    divContents.appendTo($("body"));
    //print body
    window.print();
    //remove body with DIV content
    $("html body").remove();
    //attach original body
    body.appendTo($("html"));`
```

With this, you can retain the client side events associated to the controls on page after rebinding.

Comment: I came up with an alternative solution, which is simply to open a new window, stuff the HTML into it, and print it. Works fine for me.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this:
edit: using position absolute. Realized that position:fixed only creates one page since thats how it works (you cannot scroll with position:fixed). Absolute does the same thing but is expandable.

```
@media print {
    body * {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    #divname, #divname * {
        visibility: visible;
    }
    #divname {
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        position:absolute;
    }
    p {
        page-break-before: always;
    }
}
.para {
    font-size:x-large;
    height:3000px;
}
```

Comment: Including height did not make a difference.

Comment: Ok let me try it out. Can you post this example code somewhere? need more context

Comment: Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/iamraja/bsbbq248/ . The content of the body is very long so that it spans across multiple pages. However, the print only prints one page.

Comment: Print on the fiddle above works fine after removing position: fixed; attribute. But in my actual print, I need that to align the grid/table in the div to the left of the page. Also, even without the position attribute, it still prints one page. I could not include the original code due to security reasons. Any ideas?

Comment: sorry this is the first time I using fiddle and i might have over written your code, can you pls double check if I did not remove anything you added?

Comment: its fine, replace css with above^

Comment: Works on that fiddle. But does not work in my actual code. No content is displayed on print until position: fixed attribute is added. And then prints just one page. Any clue?

Comment: try above answer again :P, i use position absolute instead of fixed.

Comment: In my original code, there is no <p>. It's just a long table with several tr's. How to apply break on it? Also, what happens when there are multiple @media print styles? (i.e one for each 3rd party component used in the project)

Comment: for page break, you can just add a new <div class="pageBreak"></div> element, and do .pageBreak { page-break-before:always }.
If there are third party media print styles... then im not sure :P

Comment: print:absolute does it for me on the parent container of the content I wish to print.

Answer (score 27):

**CSS**

```
@media print {
  * { overflow: visible !important; } 
  .page { page-break-after:always; }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <div class="page">
    Page 1 Contents
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    Page 2 Contents
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `* { overflow: visible !important; } ` has helped in my case, thank you!

Comment: It helped me too, but I didnt have to separate the content into multiple div tags one per page..

Answer (score 15):

I got the same problem right now and tried almost everything (clearing floats, avoiding absolute positioning, adding overflows, ...) without any effect.

Then I found a fix, so simple that it hurts:

```css
body, #main-container {
  height: auto;
}
```

---

*I think this may is the solution only for some edge cases, but as I didn't find this solution when I was searching before and fiddling around with many non-working-solutions, I think it should at least be mentioned for people that don't get it working with the "usual tips"*.

Answer (score 3):

You can force Chrome to emulate "print" mode, which makes it **much** easier to troubleshoot these finicky `@media print` issues:

[Using Chrome's Element Inspector in Print Preview Mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540990/using-chromes-element-inspector-in-print-preview-mode)

Once it's enabled, you can change the CSS for the print view on the fly and see what'll work for you.