# How to print only First page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, printing

I am trying to print a document,used `@page` css rule to define the page dimensions, but a blank page is always created at the bottom .I need to print only the first page. Is it possible to print only the first page using CSS or JQuery. Or is there any way to avoid creating blank pages at the bottom or to remove it.

Comment: yes it is possible but it is similar question to this post 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187715/css-print-media-query-prints-only-first-page

Comment: `but a blank page is always created at the bottom` So you'd have better to ask question regarding this issue (if it is?!), not the workaround: [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @PrajwalShrestha no its different, the issue in that question was "It printing only the first page" but they required to print other pages as well

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this is possible. But then you can reduce the bottom margin of the page.

```
@page { margin: 2cm 2cm 0 2cm }
```