# Adding CSS print footers

Tags: css

I'm trying to debug why the `@bottom-right` and `@bottom-left` are having no effect when I print my page. Instead I currently get chromes default footers, and I cannot figure out how to inspect the rules to see if they are being applied.

```
<style type="text/css">
    @page {
        size: A4;
        margin: 2cm;

        @bottom-right {
            content: counter(page) ' of ' counter(pages);
        }
        @bottom-left {
            content: '©  ' attr(data-date);
        }
    }

    @media print {
        html, body {
            width: 210mm;
            height: 297mm;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Thanks!

Comment: "I cannot figure out how to inspect the rules to see if they are being applied" See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540990/using-chromes-element-inspector-in-print-preview-mode) works for you. Your `html` selector has a wayward @, although I'm guessing that's just a copy error.

Comment: Thanks yeah was a mistake. Still doesn't affect the question. I've tried putting it into emulation, but where does the footer content go in this emulated mode?