# Print website (chrome and angular) is not working (blank)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, browser, printdialog

My website system is running on chrome 37+ and using Angular.js and bootstrap.

For some reason, I can't print my website.
When i try to print my website (using the browser print dialog), I usually get a blank print preview ("can not load print preview"). Sometimes it is not blank, but not really show my website.

I tried to run my website on some google chrome versions and some computers and it is not working.
I have been searching for reasons, but can't find one that will fix this issue.

Let my know for reasons for this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a URL i can look at?

Comment: Are you using any print media(css) ..?

Comment: Bootstrap has printing issues in Chrome. Check out this link for more info: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-printing

Comment: Sorry I don't have a link. It is on separate network.

Comment: I am not using any print media

Answer (score 0):

Chrome actually does have emulation of printing. See [image: Chrome console screenie]

You'll find this in a tab adjacent to console within developer tools. By enabling CSS media on print, you'll see your site with any print media applied. Once enabled, you may use the element inspection as usual to see how those extra css rules affect your site.

In particular, bootstrap will remove any background, and run a bunch of defaults across many typical elements.

Also, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21156904/2923245

Comment: Meaning, that after you enabled CSS media print, everything still looked fine?

Comment: No. Nothing changed. I still have the blank print preview.