# How to change the print layout of Grails

Tags: css

[image: Print View of Grails]

This is how the table of an employee page looks when I want to print it.
How do I change the layout to be able to print out something close to 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing much to do with **Grails**, rather than **CSS**.

> To style pages for printing, you have to use **CSS media query**

That code in your `css` looks like this:

```
@media print {
  all your element styles for printing
 }
```

You can also have a different file for printing like this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="print.css">`

*See more info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp) and [here for inspecting print styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540990/using-chromes-element-inspector-in-print-preview-mode)*

Comment: thank you, I edited my post to include css, I placed the tag grails since i didn't know where to start with this or where to put the additional file for printing

Comment: gsp file stays the same and you don't change it (obviously). css file for printing is in the same folder as the rest of the css files (or you just include css media query in your regular css file). just one little media query (in which you put the regular css stuff) does the trick.