# Chrome:How to print whole page in google chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am developing a drawing tool using HTML tag `div`,`a`,etc. The tool needs a large page over A4 paper size (over 297mm x 210mm) or A3 paper size. I would like to print the whole page in chrome. But chrome prints the left end paper size only.
How do I print the whole page in chrome?

I do not care about horizontal multiple paper pages printed and I also do not care if the answer is about Chrome settings or JavaScript code.

Comment: Please attach an example HTML

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540990/using-chromes-element-inspector-in-print-preview-mode) to find out how you can use dev tools to emulate print mode. This will help you in writing the proper css to print the page how you want it.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply and thank you for the advice.Although I tried according to your advice, the problem was not resolved.