# This is a snackbar message appearing in printouts

Tags: highcharts, snackbar

I've purchased and installed the highcharts editor

http://www.highcharts.com/products/highcharts-editor

by including the relevant JS and CSS files in my HTML templates.

However, whenever a browser page is printed, a box with the text 'This is a snackbar' and an 'action' button appears.

It doesn't appear on screen in the browser, only when the print dialog is opened, from the second page as per the attached screenshot.

What is it and how can it be removed?

The browser is Google Chrome.

[image: snackbar]

Comment: Try this and override with CSS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540990/using-chromes-element-inspector-in-print-preview-mode

Comment: Thanks, that's a great tip and useful for the future, but it doesn't help this case because the message only appears at the top of the *second* page and there are no pagebreaks in-browser even with print rendering on

Comment: Do you have a link I can test it on?