# How to Print Bootstrap Modal Exactly as the Display?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

so I'm having difficulties to print a modal with it's css. I wanted to print out a modal window exactly as it shown on the screen. I've used the **window.print()** command or even the javasript / jquery one. but the css is not attached. instead, it prints my modal only half way through.

So, what I wanted is, this modal image :
[Modal Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCllb.png)

Will be printed to **window.print()** as what it shown on the screen. the whole modal block with the borders etc. but without the page behind it.

codes I've tried :

```
function printElement(elem) {
        var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);

        var $printSection = document.getElementById("printSection");

        if (!$printSection) {
            var $printSection = document.createElement("div");
            $printSection.id = "printSection";
            document.body.appendChild($printSection);
        }

        $printSection.innerHTML = "";
        $printSection.appendChild(domClone);
        window.print();
    }
```

If anyone would answer this, Thank You !

Comment: What do you want get printed?  just model block or whole page?

Comment: just the model block but with its css, as exactly the border, etc. without the rest of the page behind it. @NitinDhomse

Comment: you need specify the style of printing on @media print mood , chrom browser has print mood that you can view the style of printing

Comment: can you explain in a code to help me understand ? @moathnaji

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@media print` tag

```
@media print {
  model.class {
     display: none; /* Hidden by default */
     position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
     z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
     left: 0;
     top: 0;
     width: 100%; /* Full width */
     height: 100%; /* Full height */
     overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
     background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
     background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
  } // or you can add what ever you want css in print mood
```

All the CSS in the `@media print` tag will be applied only in print mode, so to test the style and be sure the design deals with needs, you can use print mode in Chrome Browser.

For more information, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540990/using-chromes-element-inspector-in-print-preview-mode).