# HTML svg gragh is showing correctly on browser, but it disappear in print view

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg, browser

HTML svg gragh is showing correctly on browser web page, but it disappear in print view. How to debug it?

```
<svg>

 ....
</svg>
```

Is there a way to see HTML elements in print view?

Comment: I think we need a little more to go on than an `<svg/>` tag...

Comment: If you are asking for Chrome, this is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540990/using-chromes-element-inspector-in-print-preview-mode and so a possible duplicate post.