# Remove Hyperlink Underlines from Wikipedia Print Preview

Tags: css, printing, wikipedia

I want to print some articles from Wikipedia, but I want to remove the hyperlink underlines from all of the words in the print.

---

I'm using Wikipedia Account [User Scripts Custom CSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Printing#Controlling_print) to remove the links, but can't get it to work, the underlines still show up in Chrome's Print Preview. I created a Wikipedia `vector.css` theme override, and cleared browser cache, but I can't tell if the CSS is even applying.

[image: Custom CSS]

```
/* Remove Hyperlinks */
@media print {
    a:link {text-decoration: none !important;}
    a[href]:after {content: none !important;}
}
```

---

**Wikipedia Account Gadgets Print Options**

I'm also using [Gadgets Print Options](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:TheDJ/Print_options) to remove other elements, such as reference number links.

[image: Wikipedia Print Options]

---

**Chrome Print View**

And Chrome's Print Preview features, to reformat the page for printing.

You can see here the link underlines in the preview.

[image: Chrome Print View]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Switch [Chrome's rendering to print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540990/using-chromes-element-inspector-in-print-preview-mode) and you'll see they're  cheating with `border-bottom`.  You'll need to knock that out too:

```css
/* Remove Hyperlinks */
@media print {
    a:link {
        border-bottom: none !important;
        text-decoration: none !important;
    }
    a[href]:after {
        content: none !important;
    }
}
```