# Export HTML page to pdf in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

export-as and exporting pdf, exported pdf document is not proper it is not streching fully red mark  inserted for reference,attached image . 
Below is my config:

```
  exportAsConfig: ExportAsConfig = {
    type: 'pdf', // the type you want to download
    //elementId: 'balance-sheet-preview', // the id of html/table element
    elementId: 'contentToConvert', // the id of html/table element
    options: { // html-docx-js document options
      margins: {
        top: '20',
        bottom: '5'
      },
      orientation: 'landscape',
      filename: 'engagement.pdf',
      image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 1 },
    }
  }
```

call in function:

```
export(){
this.exportAsService.save(this.exportAsConfig, 'engagementLetter').subscribe(() => {
      // save started
    });
}
```

Any solution for this[image]

Html print snippet image:
[image]

Comment: Could you add a small snippet of HTML that allows us to recreate this issue?

Comment: Added html snippet

Comment: @Titulum any other libraries to export as pdf

Answer (score 2):

in google chrom you can set the view to print and specify media type to print then add css related to print type this css will applied only in printing mood 
use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540990/using-chromes-element-inspector-in-print-preview-mode) to check how to switch to print mood .

Comment: you can do this in backend create multiple templates with specific formats and print the whole view whenever request come from the angular side or you can use something front end in angular like   https://www.ngdevelop.tech/angular-8-export-to-pdf-using-pdfmake/

Answer (score 1):

I have lot of experience with pdf in Angular.

Among all of them best library is https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf

Example : https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/

Docs : https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/