# Spring Boot (v2.3.3): Thymeleaf & Flying Saucer PDF, HTML is Rendered Cut off the Page

Tags: html, css, spring-boot, thymeleaf, flying-saucer

I'm trying to use a Thymeleaf html template and transform it into a PDF using Flying Saucer PDF, however I am having issue with the html content being push far right. Below is an example of the generated PDF.

[image]

I'm using Bootstrap CSS v4 and a bit of inline styles. Below is a screenshot of the HTML rendered in the browser. Notice that the content is centered in the view and elements and text aren't cut off.

[image]

Here's my HTML template:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/webjars/bootstrap/4.5.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h3 class="display-4 text-center">MY FIRST THYMELEAF TO PDF PROJECT. HAVING ISSUE WITH PDF FORMATTING THOUGH.............</h3>
            <div class="text-center inline-flex">
                <span style="font-size: 2.5rem; letter-spacing: 0">Thymeleaf Template Engine</span>
                <span style="font-size: 2.0rem; opacity: 1; color: #707070; padding-left: 20px">Flying Saucer PDF</span>
            </div>
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <h2 class="display-2 float-right">Some Jumbo Text</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here some CSS that I attempted to apply with no success.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Lato;
    src: url("../fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf") format('truetype');
}

/*@page {*/
/*    margin: 0;*/
/*}*/

/*@page :right {*/

/*    @right-middle {*/
/*        padding-right: 200vw;*/
/*        padding-left: 200vw;*/
/*    }*/

/*    @top-right {*/
/*        content: "My Quote";*/
/*        margin: 30pt 0 10pt 0;*/
/*    }*/
/*}*/

/*@page :right {*/
/*    margin-right: 1cm;*/
/*}*/

/*@page {*/
/*    !*size: 5.5in 8.5in;*!*/
/*    margin: 0;*/

/*    @right-middle {*/
/*        !*margin: 30pt 0 10pt 0;*!*/
/*    }*/

/*    !*@top-left-corner {*!*/
/*    !*    content: url("/images/logo.png");*!*/
/*    !*    width: 200px;*!*/
/*    !*    height: 50px;*!*/
/*    !*}*!*/

/*    @top-right {*/
/*        content: "My PDF";*/
/*        !*margin: 30pt 0 10pt 0;*!*/
/*    }*/
/*}*/
```

I've tried formatting the page margins with the `@page` css annotation be nothing above helped adjust the content. Any help would be absolutely fantastic! Thanks!

Comment: Is the screenshot from browser from print preview mode? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540990/using-chromes-element-inspector-in-print-preview-mode

Comment: The first screenshot is of the actual generated pdf opened in a browser.

Comment: @JosephFreeman did you found a solution ?

Comment: @TeddyKossoko I didn't find what I would call a proper solution, I just added 225px worth of right padding and pushed the cut off portion into view.