# How to locate a css pattern from a loaded webpage and delete it

Tags: css, developer-tools

There's an Amazon.com page that does not render in print preview and shows up blank (it is the *Online Return Center\Your Return Summary page*). Through a lot of trial and error on a local saved copy of the page I found the culprit in some buggy linked stylesheet that was making everything hidden during a print preview...

```css
@media print {
    body *, header {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

However back at the original website I'm struggling to locate that source from the live page in the developer tools. Where can I look up this sort of structure from the developer tools and override it so that the print preview renders as expected?

---

**What I've tried**

So far from the `Elements` view I'm searching for all `link rel="stylesheet"` hits and manually following all the `hrefs` to the css and searching for keyword *print*. That wound up working, but when I delete the link tag and go back to the page to print I still get the same blank page. Maybe it's a server side bug?

Here's the link found in the `head` section

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/01WIasbg6mL._RC|014yivy0BxL.css_.css?AUIClients/PREXWebAppBuzzAssets-confirmationPage">
```

What can I do locally to remove this bad css?

Here's the preview I'm talking about
[image: blank print preview page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments on the author's answer:

For a single remove-and-print, you could try to [force Chrome to use the `screen` styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540990/using-chromes-element-inspector-in-print-preview-mode/21156904#21156904) even when it would normally use `print` by reversing the steps in the linked answer.

---

If using Chrome Open up developer tools, click on the 3 vertical dots in the top right corner, go to `More tools` --> `Rendering`
[image: revealing the Rendering tools dev tool page]

Then locate the `Emulate CSS media type` list box and select `Screen`. Trigger a print and review the print preview and inspect if the content renders as expected and proceed to print.

[image: selecting css media type emulation for screen]

Comment: I'm trying to hunt down an equivalent in Safari, not sure if they have similar overrides. Aha, looks like this is the closest thing https://css-tricks.com/can-you-view-print-stylesheets-applied-directly-in-the-browser/#aa-in-safari. Maybe not however, there mode is `Force Media Print Styles` button, but when I do that I see the white background because the print styles is the broken thing on this Amazon page. There's no cross-over mode that I can see like Chrome has. I want to force screen because the print preview style is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Oh wait, I'm not sure what I failed to do previously but when I just right clicked the link tag in the Elements view of the developer tools and selected `Delete element` the preview now works as expected. That wound up deleting the entire effects of the whole stylesheet, I wonder if there's a more nimble way to just cut out that select `@media print` portion

Comment: For a single remove-and-print, you could try to [force Chrome to use the `screen` styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540990/using-chromes-element-inspector-in-print-preview-mode/21156904#21156904) even when it would normally use `print` by reversing the steps in the linked answer.

Comment: That emulation on screen did the trick! Post an answer and I'll accept it and upload some screenshots to it.