# How to inspect print page?

Tags: html, printing, media, preview, print-css

I wanted find out how I could inspect my print css just like when i inspect my elements with the normal css.
I want to  inspect print preview page

I want to  inspect print preview page inchrome browswer to see my css and html format

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Chrome's Element Inspector in Print Preview Mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540990/using-chromes-element-inspector-in-print-preview-mode)

Answer (score 0):

to preview print webpage you need to do:
Press CTRL+P
Document print as it appears in window and not as in a browser
to change content that you want to print, you need to edit your website