I want to print a html table but the style is not applying to the table after adding style @media print also
I want to print a table using javascript by window.print() in the javascript but after adding the style for the tr:nth-child(even) in the @media print also it is not applying but the border none is working fine I Can't find the solution for it.I have provided my Javascript code below.
I have tryed all the methods to make the background color to have effect at print screen.I Also used linking the bootstrap cdn to have the effect. It also all the appoaches to have the strip effect.
 function generatePDF() {
    var contentToPrint;
    var example2 = document.getElementById('example2');
    var select_date = document.querySelector('#daterange-btn span');
    var date = select_date.textContent;


    if (example2.style.display === 'none') {
        contentToPrint = document.getElementById('example1').innerHTML;
    } else {
        contentToPrint = example2.innerHTML;
    }
    var printWindow = window.open('', '_blank');
    printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Print</title>');
    printWindow.document.write('<style>');
    printWindow.document.write('@media print {');
    printWindow.document.write('.no-print { display: none; }');
    printWindow.document.write('table { border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }');
    printWindow.document.write('th, td { border: none; padding: 8px; }'); 
    printWindow.document.write('th { display: none; }'); // Hide table header
    printWindow.document.write('.table-striped tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f2f2;}'); 
    printWindow.document.write('a { text-decoration: none; color: inherit; }');
    printWindow.document.write('}');
    printWindow.document.write('</style>');
    printWindow.document.write('</head><body>');
    printWindow.document.write('<h2>Bagged Items Report</h2>'); 
    printWindow.document.write('<p>'+date+'</p>');
    printWindow.document.write('<h4 style="border-bottom:2px solid black;">Search Results</h4>');
    printWindow.document.write(contentToPrint);
    printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');

    printWindow.document.close();

    // Print the content
    printWindow.print();
    }


See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540990/using-chromes-element-inspector-in-print-preview-mode for how you can emulate @media print in DevTools to debug this.

We can help you debug, but only if you include all the relevant code. We'll at least need the HTML which goes with this (the contents of example1 and example2).

Your code is fine, just make sure your browser is allowing backgrounds to be printed.

Yeah, when I tick on the background graphics settings it is showing the background color in the print preview. Is there any way to defaultly set to apply background color here.

I don't think that can be in your control, it's up to the user.
