Printing HTML to Zebra Receipt printer is printing blank
I have a web app that is attempting to print this receipt to a Zebra GX430t thermal receipt printer:

Unfortunately, it only prints whitespace.
When I print receipt to a normal printer, it prints fine. When I recreate the receipt in Word using the exact same fonts and print to receipt printer, it prints fine.
I have tried to make sure that what is being printed is not too large. The paper is 3.1 inches wide. My receipt is 250px, or 2.6 inches wide. I have tried using @media print in my CSS. This did not work.
I've included everything I can, HTML, CSS, JS. This isn't the entire page, however.
I am working with LaserFiche Forms which injects all kind of crap into the page, (CSS etc.). I can't see the whole thing. I've included just the stuff I've edited.
The reason for the !important splattered all over the CSS is because of the way their primary CSS is written, it's been difficult to make my changes override theirs.
I just don't understand why it's showing up blank when it prints.


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.Submit').hide();
  $(document).prop('title', 'Ticket');
  $('.hr').append('<hr>');
  $("#Field24").attr("id", "ticket-title");
  $("#Field6").attr("id", "ticket-barcode");

  $(document).on("onloadlookupfinished", function() {
    $('#Field26').val($('#Field26').val().split(" ")[0]);
    $('#Field19').val($('#Field19').val().split(" ")[0]);
    $('#Field18').val(new Date().toLocaleString());
    parent.postMessage("printme", "*");
  });

  $(document).on("lookupcomplete", function(e) {
    $('#ticket-title').val($('#Field1').val())
    var barcode_value = "*" + $('#Field1').val() + "*";
    $('#ticket-barcode').val(barcode_value);
  });
});
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Libre+Barcode+128&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap');

/*I have tried it both with and without this @media print thingy. */

@media print {
  .cf-section-block {
    white-space: nowrap !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
  }
  .cf-label {
    /*Notice that the font family is turned off here*/
    /*font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif !important;*/
    font-size: 12px !important;
    width: 100px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
  }
  .cf-table {
    /*font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif !important;*/
    font-size: 12px !important;
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
  }
  .cf-table input {
    /*font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif !important;*/
    font-size: 12px !important;
    border-width: 0px !important;
  }
  .cf-medium,
  .cf-field {
    /*font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif !important;*/
    font-size: 12px !important;
    width: 150px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
    border-width: 0px !important;
    height: 20px !important;
  }
  #ticket-title {
    /*font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif !important;*/
    font-weight: 500 !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
    font-size: 20px !important;
    width: 250px !important;
    background-color: #FFF !important;
    border-width: 0px !important;
    text-align: center !important;
  }
  #ticket-barcode {
    font-family: "Libre Barcode 128", system-ui !important;
    font-weight: 400 !important;
    font-style: normal !important;
    font-size: 45px !important;
    height: 30px !important;
    background-color: #FFF !important;
    border-width: 0px !important;
    width: 250px !important;
    text-align: center !important;
  }
  ul li.form-q {
    padding: 0px 0px !important;
    white-space: nowrap !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
  }
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="cf-page active" id="q0">
    <div id="q2" class="cf-section-block hidden lf-container-hidden" readonlysection="false" aria-hidden="true">
      <ul>
        <li attr="TicketID" attrtype="text" name="q4" id="q4" class="form-q label-left">
          <label class="cf-label" id="FieldLabel4" for="Field4"><span><span>TicketID</span></span><span class="screen-reader-legend">field type single line</span></label>
          <div class="cf-field">
            <input type="text" id="Field4" name="Field4" aria-labelledby="FieldLabel4" class="singleline cf-medium lf-no-validate" maxlength="4000" data-list-focus="true" data-parsley-legal-character="True" vo="u" disabled user-preset="620" aria-invalid="false">
          </div>
        </li>

        <li attr="TicketTypeID" attrtype="text" name="q5" id="q5" class="form-q label-left">
          <label class="cf-label" id="FieldLabel5" for="Field5"><span><span>TicketTypeID</span></span><span class="screen-reader-legend">field type single line</span></label>
          <div class="cf-field awesomplete">
            <input type="text" id="Field5" name="Field5" aria-labelledby="FieldLabel5" class="singleline cf-medium lf-no-validate awesomplete" maxlength="4000" data-list-focus="true" data-parsley-legal-character="True" vo="e" disabled aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="off"
              aria-autocomplete="list" awesomelast="" lookupalt="true">
          </div>
        </li>

        <li attr="TicketNumber" attrtype="text" name="q1" id="q1" class="montserrat-title form-q label-left">
          <label class="cf-label" id="FieldLabel1" for="Field1"><span><span>Ticket Number:</span></span><span class="screen-reader-legend">field type single line</span></label>

          <div class="cf-field awesomplete">
            <input type="text" id="Field1" name="Field1" aria-labelledby="FieldLabel1" class="singleline cf-medium lf-no-validate awesomplete" maxlength="4000" data-list-focus="true" data-parsley-legal-character="True" vo="e" disabled aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="off"
              aria-autocomplete="list" awesomelast="" lookupalt="true">
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="q3" class="cf-section-block" readonlysection="false">
      <ul>
        <li attr="TicketNumberTitle" attrtype="text" name="q24" id="q24" class="form-q label-left">
          <label class="cf-label" id="FieldLabel24" for="Field24"><span><span>Ticket Number:</span></span><span class="screen-reader-legend">field type single line</span></label>

          <div class="cf-field">
            <input type="text" id="ticket-title" name="Field24" aria-labelledby="FieldLabel24" class="singleline cf-medium" maxlength="4000" data-list-focus="true" data-parsley-legal-character="True" vo="e" aria-invalid="false">
          </div>
        </li>

        <li attr="TicketNumber_Barcode" attrtype="text" name="q6" id="q6" class="barcode form-q label-left">
          <label class="cf-label" id="FieldLabel6" for="Field6"><span><span>Barcode:</span></span><span class="screen-reader-legend">field type single line</span></label>

          <div class="cf-field">
            <input type="text" id="ticket-barcode" name="Field6" aria-labelledby="FieldLabel6" class="singleline cf-medium" maxlength="4000" data-list-focus="true" data-parsley-legal-character="True" vo="e" aria-invalid="false">
          </div>
        </li>

        <li attr="" attrtype="custom" name="q22" id="q22" class="form-q label-left">
          <div class="cf-custom" id="Field22">
            <p class="hr"></p>
            <hr>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li attr="Operator_" attrtype="text" name="q7" id="q7" class="form-q label-left form-focused">
          <label class="cf-label" id="FieldLabel7" for="Field7"><span><span>Operator:</span></span><span class="screen-reader-legend">field type single line</span></label>

          <div class="cf-field awesomplete">
            <input type="text" id="Field7" name="Field7" aria-labelledby="FieldLabel7" class="singleline cf-medium awesomplete parsley-success" maxlength="4000" data-list-focus="true" data-parsley-legal-character="True" vo="e" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="list"
              awesomelast="Sammy Marks" lookupalt="true" data-parsley-id="15">
            <ul class="awesomplete-child cf-medium" hidden="">
              <li aria-selected="false" class="ellipsis" title="Sammy Marks">
                <mark>Sammy Marks</mark>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li attr="Department_" attrtype="text" name="q8" id="q8" class="form-q label-left">
          <label class="cf-label" id="FieldLabel8" for="Field8"><span><span>Department:</span></span><span class="screen-reader-legend">field type single line</span></label>

          <div class="cf-field awesomplete">
            <input type="text" id="Field8" name="Field8" aria-labelledby="FieldLabel8" class="singleline cf-medium awesomplete" maxlength="4000" data-list-focus="true" data-parsley-legal-character="True" vo="e" aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="list"
              awesomelast="" lookupalt="true">
          </div>
        </li>

        <li attr="Mach__Name" attrtype="text" name="q9" id="q9" class="form-q label-left">
          <label class="cf-label" id="FieldLabel9" for="Field9"><span><span>Mach. Name:</span></span><span class="screen-reader-legend">field type single line</span></label>

          <div class="cf-field awesomplete">
            <input type="text" id="Field9" name="Field9" aria-labelledby="FieldLabel9" class="singleline cf-medium awesomplete" maxlength="4000" data-list-focus="true" data-parsley-legal-character="True" vo="e" aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="list"
              awesomelast="" lookupalt="true">
          </div>
        </li>

        <li attr="Mach__Grp" attrtype="text" name="q10" id="q10" class="form-q label-left">
          <label class="cf-label" id="FieldLabel10" for="Field10"><span><span>Mach. Grp:</span></span><span class="screen-reader-legend">field type single line</span></label>

          <div class="cf-field awesomplete">
            <input type="text" id="Field10" name="Field10" aria-labelledby="FieldLabel10" class="singleline cf-medium awesomplete" maxlength="4000" data-list-focus="true" data-parsley-legal-character="True" vo="e" aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="list"
              awesomelast="" lookupalt="true">
          </div>
        </li>

        <li attr="Cell_Leader_" attrtype="text" name="q11" id="q11" class="form-q label-left">
          <label class="cf-label" id="FieldLabel11" for="Field11"><span><span>Cell Leader:</span></span><span class="screen-reader-legend">field type single line</span></label>

          <div class="cf-field awesomplete">
            <input type="text" id="Field11" name="Field11" aria-labelledby="FieldLabel11" class="singleline cf-medium awesomplete" maxlength="4000" data-list-focus="true" data-parsley-legal-character="True" vo="e" aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="list"
              awesomelast="" lookupalt="true">

            <p class="screen-reader-legend">Input blocked. Maximum character limit of 4000 characters reached.</p>

            <ul hidden="" class="awesomplete-child cf-medium"></ul>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li attr="Part_Number_" attrtype="text" name="q25" id="q25" class="form-q label-left">
          <label class="cf-label" id="FieldLabel25" for="Field25"><span><span>Part Number:</span></span><span class="screen-reader-legend">field type single line</span></label>

          <div class="cf-field awesomplete">
            <input type="text" id="Field25" name="Field25" aria-labelledby="FieldLabel25" class="singleline cf-medium awesomplete" maxlength="4000" data-list-focus="true" data-parsley-legal-character="True" vo="e" aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="list"
              awesomelast="" lookupalt="true">
          </div>
        </li>

        <li attr="Job_Lot_" attrtype="text" name="q12" id="q12" class="form-q label-left">
          <label class="cf-label" id="FieldLabel12" for="Field12"><span><span>Job/Lot:</span></span><span class="screen-reader-legend">field type single line</span></label>

          <div class="cf-field awesomplete">
            <input type="text" id="Field12" name="Field12" aria-labelledby="FieldLabel12" class="singleline cf-medium awesomplete" maxlength="4000" data-list-focus="true" data-parsley-legal-character="True" vo="e" aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="list"
              awesomelast="" lookupalt="true">
          </div>
        </li>

        <li attr="" attrtype="custom" name="q23" id="q23" class="form-q label-left">
          <div class="cf-custom" id="Field23">
            <p class="hr"></p>
            <hr>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li attr="Pins" attrtype="table" name="q16" id="q16" class="form-q label-left cf-table-block label-left">
          <div class="cf-section-header">
            <h2>Pins</h2>
          </div>

          <div class="cf-table_parent">
            <table summary="Pins" class="cf-table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="hideRowLabel" style="display:none"></th>

                  <th width="0%" id="q13" class="form-q"><label class="cf-col-label" id="FieldLabel13(1)" for="Field13(1)">Diam.<span class="screen-reader-legend">field type single line</span></label></th>

                  <th width="0%" id="q14" class="form-q"><label class="cf-col-label" id="FieldLabel14(1)" for="Field14(1)"># Pins<span class="screen-reader-legend">field type single line</span></label></th>

                  <th width="0%" id="q17" class="form-q"><label class="cf-col-label" id="FieldLabel17(1)" for="Field17(1)">Type<span class="screen-reader-legend">field type single line</span></label></th>

                  <th></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>

              <tbody repeatrowlabel="Row {n}" backendrowcount="{&quot;13&quot;:5,&quot;14&quot;:5,&quot;17&quot;:5}" class="kx-repeatable">
                <tr style="">
                  <td data-col="q13" data-title="Diam.">
                    <label class="cf-col-label" id="FieldLabel13(1)" for="Field13(1)">Diam.<span class="screen-reader-legend">field type single line</span></label>

                    <div class="cf-field">
                      <input type="text" id="Field13(1)" name="Field13(1)" aria-labelledby="FieldLabel13(1)" class="singleline cf-xlarge" maxlength="4000" data-list-focus="true" data-parsley-legal-character="True" vo="k" list="datalist13" lookupalt="true">
                      <input type="hidden" name="PopulatedField13(1)" value="0" id="PopulatedField13(1)">
                    </div>
                  </td>

                  <td data-col="q14" data-title="# Pins">
                    <label class="cf-col-label" id="FieldLabel14(1)" for="Field14(1)"># Pins<span class="screen-reader-legend">field type single line</span></label>

                    <div class="cf-field">
                      <input type="text" id="Field14(1)" name="Field14(1)" aria-labelledby="FieldLabel14(1)" class="singleline cf-xlarge" maxlength="4000" data-list-focus="true" data-parsley-legal-character="True" vo="k" list="datalist14" lookupalt="true">
                      <input type="hidden" name="PopulatedField14(1)" value="0" id="PopulatedField14(1)">
                    </div>
                  </td>

                  <td data-col="q17" data-title="Type">
                    <label class="cf-col-label" id="FieldLabel17(1)" for="Field17(1)">Type<span class="screen-reader-legend">field type single line</span></label>

                    <div class="cf-field">
                      <input type="text" id="Field17(1)" name="Field17(1)" aria-labelledby="FieldLabel17(1)" class="singleline cf-xlarge" maxlength="4000" data-list-focus="true" data-parsley-legal-character="True" vo="k" list="datalist17" lookupalt="true">
                      <input type="hidden" name="PopulatedField17(1)" value="0" id="PopulatedField17(1)">

                    </div>
                  </td>

                </tr>

                <tr style="">
                  <td data-col="q13" data-title="Diam.">
                    <label class="cf-col-label" id="FieldLabel13(2)" for="Field13(2)">Diam.<span class="screen-reader-legend">field type single line</span></label>

                    <div class="cf-field">
                      <input type="text" id="Field13(2)" name="Field13(2)" aria-labelledby="FieldLabel13(2)" class="singleline cf-xlarge" maxlength="4000" data-list-focus="true" data-parsley-legal-character="True" vo="k" list="datalist13" lookupalt="true">
                      <input type="hidden" name="PopulatedField13(2)" value="1" id="PopulatedField13(2)">
                    </div>
                  </td>

                  <td data-col="q14" data-title="# Pins">
                    <label class="cf-col-label" id="FieldLabel14(2)" for="Field14(2)"># Pins<span class="screen-reader-legend">field type single line</span></label>

                    <div class="cf-field">
                      <input type="text" id="Field14(2)" name="Field14(2)" aria-labelledby="FieldLabel14(2)" class="singleline cf-xlarge" maxlength="4000" data-list-focus="true" data-parsley-legal-character="True" vo="k" list="datalist14" lookupalt="true">
                      <input type="hidden" name="PopulatedField14(2)" value="1" id="PopulatedField14(2)">
                    </div>
                  </td>

                  <td data-col="q17" data-title="Type">
                    <label class="cf-col-label" id="FieldLabel17(2)" for="Field17(2)">Type<span class="screen-reader-legend">field type single line</span></label>

                    <div class="cf-field">
                      <input type="text" id="Field17(2)" name="Field17(2)" aria-labelledby="FieldLabel17(2)" class="singleline cf-xlarge" maxlength="4000" data-list-focus="true" data-parsley-legal-character="True" vo="k" list="datalist17" lookupalt="true">
                      <input type="hidden" name="PopulatedField17(2)" value="1" id="PopulatedField17(2)">
                    </div>
                  </td>

                </tr>

                <tr style="">
                  <td data-col="q13" data-title="Diam.">
                    <label class="cf-col-label" id="FieldLabel13(3)" for="Field13(3)">Diam.<span class="screen-reader-legend">field type single line</span></label>

                    <div class="cf-field">
                      <input type="text" id="Field13(3)" name="Field13(3)" aria-labelledby="FieldLabel13(3)" class="singleline cf-xlarge" maxlength="4000" data-list-focus="true" data-parsley-legal-character="True" vo="k" list="datalist13" lookupalt="true">
                      <input type="hidden" name="PopulatedField13(3)" value="2" id="PopulatedField13(3)">
                    </div>
                  </td>

                  <td data-col="q14" data-title="# Pins">
                    <label class="cf-col-label" id="FieldLabel14(3)" for="Field14(3)"># Pins<span class="screen-reader-legend">field type single line</span></label>

                    <div class="cf-field">
                      <input type="text" id="Field14(3)" name="Field14(3)" aria-labelledby="FieldLabel14(3)" class="singleline cf-xlarge" maxlength="4000" data-list-focus="true" data-parsley-legal-character="True" vo="k" list="datalist14" lookupalt="true">
                      <input type="hidden" name="PopulatedField14(3)" value="2" id="PopulatedField14(3)">
                    </div>
                  </td>

                  <td data-col="q17" data-title="Type">
                    <label class="cf-col-label" id="FieldLabel17(3)" for="Field17(3)">Type<span class="screen-reader-legend">field type single line</span></label>

                    <div class="cf-field">
                      <input type="text" id="Field17(3)" name="Field17(3)" aria-labelledby="FieldLabel17(3)" class="singleline cf-xlarge" maxlength="4000" data-list-focus="true" data-parsley-legal-character="True" vo="k" list="datalist17" lookupalt="true">
                      <input type="hidden" name="PopulatedField17(3)" value="2" id="PopulatedField17(3)">
                    </div>
                  </td>

                </tr>

                <tr style="">

                  <td data-col="q13" data-title="Diam.">
                    <label class="cf-col-label" id="FieldLabel13(4)" for="Field13(4)">Diam.<span class="screen-reader-legend">field type single line</span></label>

                    <div class="cf-field">
                      <input type="text" id="Field13(4)" name="Field13(4)" aria-labelledby="FieldLabel13(4)" class="singleline cf-xlarge" maxlength="4000" data-list-focus="true" data-parsley-legal-character="True" vo="k" list="datalist13" lookupalt="true">
                      <input type="hidden" name="PopulatedField13(4)" value="3" id="PopulatedField13(4)">
                    </div>
                  </td>

                  <td data-col="q14" data-title="# Pins">
                    <label class="cf-col-label" id="FieldLabel14(4)" for="Field14(4)"># Pins<span class="screen-reader-legend">field type single line</span></label>

                    <div class="cf-field">
                      <input type="text" id="Field14(4)" name="Field14(4)" aria-labelledby="FieldLabel14(4)" class="singleline cf-xlarge" maxlength="4000" data-list-focus="true" data-parsley-legal-character="True" vo="k" list="datalist14" lookupalt="true">
                      <input type="hidden" name="PopulatedField14(4)" value="3" id="PopulatedField14(4)">
                    </div>
                  </td>

                  <td data-col="q17" data-title="Type">
                    <label class="cf-col-label" id="FieldLabel17(4)" for="Field17(4)">Type<span class="screen-reader-legend">field type single line</span></label>

                    <div class="cf-field">
                      <input type="text" id="Field17(4)" name="Field17(4)" aria-labelledby="FieldLabel17(4)" class="singleline cf-xlarge" maxlength="4000" data-list-focus="true" data-parsley-legal-character="True" vo="k" list="datalist17" lookupalt="true">
                      <input type="hidden" name="PopulatedField17(4)" value="3" id="PopulatedField17(4)">
                    </div>
                  </td>

                </tr>

                <tr style="">
                  <td data-col="q13" data-title="Diam.">
                    <label class="cf-col-label" id="FieldLabel13(5)" for="Field13(5)">Diam.<span class="screen-reader-legend">field type single line</span></label>
                    <div class="cf-field">
                      <input type="text" id="Field13(5)" name="Field13(5)" aria-labelledby="FieldLabel13(5)" class="singleline cf-xlarge" maxlength="4000" data-list-focus="true" data-parsley-legal-character="True" vo="k" list="datalist13" lookupalt="true">
                      <input type="hidden" name="PopulatedField13(5)" value="4" id="PopulatedField13(5)">
                    </div>
                  </td>

                  <td data-col="q14" data-title="# Pins">
                    <label class="cf-col-label" id="FieldLabel14(5)" for="Field14(5)"># Pins<span class="screen-reader-legend">field type single line</span></label>

                    <div class="cf-field">
                      <input type="text" id="Field14(5)" name="Field14(5)" aria-labelledby="FieldLabel14(5)" class="singleline cf-xlarge" maxlength="4000" data-list-focus="true" data-parsley-legal-character="True" vo="k" list="datalist14" lookupalt="true">
                      <input type="hidden" name="PopulatedField14(5)" value="4" id="PopulatedField14(5)">
                    </div>
                  </td>

                  <td data-col="q17" data-title="Type">
                    <label class="cf-col-label" id="FieldLabel17(5)" for="Field17(5)">Type<span class="screen-reader-legend">field type single line</span></label>

                    <div class="cf-field">
                      <input type="text" id="Field17(5)" name="Field17(5)" aria-labelledby="FieldLabel17(5)" class="singleline cf-xlarge" maxlength="4000" data-list-focus="true" data-parsley-legal-character="True" vo="k" list="datalist17" lookupalt="true">
                      <input type="hidden" name="PopulatedField17(5)" value="4" id="PopulatedField17(5)">
                    </div>
                  </td>

                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li attr="" attrtype="custom" name="q21" id="q21" class="form-q label-left">
          <div class="cf-custom" id="Field21">
            <p class="hr"></p>
            <hr>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li attr="Date_Printed" attrtype="text" name="q18" id="q18" class="form-q label-left">
          <label class="cf-label" id="FieldLabel18" for="Field18"><span><span>Printed:</span></span><span class="screen-reader-legend">field type single line</span></label>

          <div class="cf-field">
            <input type="text" id="Field18" name="Field18" aria-labelledby="FieldLabel18" class="singleline cf-medium" maxlength="4000" data-list-focus="true" data-parsley-legal-character="True" vo="e" aria-invalid="false">
          </div>
        </li>

        <li attr="Last_Cal_Date_" attrtype="text" name="q26" id="q26" class="form-q label-left">
          <label class="cf-label" id="FieldLabel26" for="Field26"><span><span>Last Cal Date:</span></span><span class="screen-reader-legend">field type single line</span></label>

          <div class="cf-field awesomplete">
            <input type="text" id="Field26" name="Field26" aria-labelledby="FieldLabel26" class="singleline cf-medium awesomplete" maxlength="4000" data-list-focus="true" data-parsley-legal-character="True" vo="e" aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="list"
              awesomelast="" lookupalt="true">
          </div>
        </li>

        <li attr="Cal_Due_Date_" attrtype="text" name="q19" id="q19" class="form-q label-left">
          <label class="cf-label" id="FieldLabel19" for="Field19"><span><span>Cal Due Date:</span></span><span class="screen-reader-legend">field type single line</span></label>

          <div class="cf-field awesomplete">
            <input type="text" id="Field19" name="Field19" aria-labelledby="FieldLabel19" class="singleline cf-medium awesomplete" maxlength="4000" data-list-focus="true" data-parsley-legal-character="True" vo="e" aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="list"
              awesomelast="" lookupalt="true">
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>




Maybe something else from the "rest" of the page is still visible, and pushes the receipt part out of the print area on this narrow print device? I'd try and emulate print CSS in Chrome (https://stackoverflow.com/q/9540990/1427878), and then check how it looks when you test using a similarly narrow viewport.
